# image caption slide from top on hover

Tags: jquery

I have a caption that is fading in on hover and then sliding down when the mouse leaves. How can I change this so that the caption slides down from the top of the image on mouseenter and then slides up again on mouseleave?

```
<a href="link.html">
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <img alt="" width="184" height="69" src="image.png" />
        <div class="description">
            <div class="description_content">Title<br /><small>Description text</small></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){  
        $('div.description').each(function(){  
        $(this).css('opacity', 0);  
        $(this).css('width', $(this).siblings('img').width());  
        $(this).parent().css('width', $(this).siblings('img').width());  
        $(this).css('display', 'block');  
    });  

$('div.wrapper').mouseenter(function(){    
    $(this).children('.description').stop().fadeTo(700, 1);  
}).mouseleave(function(){  
    $(this).children('.description').stop().slideUp(700);  
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('div.wrapper').mouseenter(function(){    
    $(this).children('.description').stop().slideDown(700);  
}).mouseleave(function(){  
    $(this).children('.description').stop().slideUp(700);  
});
```

Comment: Nothing happens with this. Nothing appears.